# WebView properties don't work if the app is launched via a Push Notification

Tags: ios, webview, notifications, react-native, push

Our app uses a webview to load some part of our app. But we've stumbled across a scenario where we found the [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onloadend) properties don't work if the app has a cold start via a Push Notification

**When the application is launched normally:**  We get to the React Native page and once the page is done loading we get the alert created in `onLoadEnd`

**App is launched via a remote push notification:** When the app is removed from memory by double clicking the home button and swiping the app away, and the user clicks on a Push Notification which launches the app - The page loads perfectly fine **BUT** the function `onLoadEnd` does NOT run.

```
  render() {
    return(
         <View style={ styles.iosPadding }>

           <WebView
             source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
             onLoadEnd={() => {
               alert("Webpage Loaded !");
             }}
           />

         </View>
    );
  }
```

I've been looking around for a workaround for this scenario. What I need is the ability to know when the webpage is loaded.

Comment: You should file a Github issue.

Comment: @rclai : I was a little apprehensive about creating an issue on the RN github repo as there are already so many there (1000+ issues). But I went ahead and created on anyways. 

Here is the link for ref: 

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10044